# Binary Conditional Formatting

Tags: conditional-statements, binary, excel-365

I'm using Excel 365 and I need help with the following problem regarding conditional formatting with Binary values.

I would like if a certain cell is larger than 0, for another cell to return the number 1. If the first cell is 0 or smaller than 0, the second cell should return 0.

Anyone know how to do this?

I tried regular conditional formatting with the number formatting, but it just returns the value of the first cell if it's larger than 0.

I've looked up several tutorials, but none of them are useful in this specific situation

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking for an IF statement, not conditional formatting.

If the cell you want to watch is A1, try entering "=IF(A1>0,1,0)" in another cell.  Change A1 to the value of the cell you want to watch.